# Checking in the code using tortoiseSVN that is checked out by tortoiseSVN 1.8

Tags: tortoise-svn

I have checked out the code in my workspace using Tortoise SVN 1.8. Now, due to some requirements I had to install Tortoise SVN 1.6. The code can not be checked in using SVN 1.6. Why?

Comment: You might want to help us help you - are there any error messages or logs that might be of interest?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the client-side format changed between SVN 1.6 and 1.7, making them incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

SVN 1.6 and 1.8 have completely different working copy formats and 1.6 does not understand the 1.8 format. As a result TortoiseSVN will simply ignore your existing checkout folders.

In order to be able to check files in you will need to check the files out using TortoiseSVN 1.6, you should then be able to modify and check files in again.